# Stretches that are good for stiff neck and shoulders?

Tags: stretching, shoulders, neck

Are there stretches that can help with stiff neck and shoulders?

Answer (score 1):

Here are several exercises specifically for stiff neck:

- [Chinese Holistic Exercises](http://www.chinese-holistic-health-exercises.com/stiff-neck-exercise.html) - Stiff neck exercises and tips for relief using acupuncture (consult with your health professional first before trying these, though.)
- [Yoga Exercises for neck and shoulder pain](http://www.yogajournal.com/practice/231) - Six excerises you can do at your desk to relieve tension in your wrists, back, and shoulders.
- [Stiff neck relief from eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_2101279_stiff-neck-stretching-sternocleidomastoid-muscle.html) - [Sternocleidomastoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternocleidomastoid_muscle) muscle stretching for stiff neck and neck mobility enchancement .

Comment: Hi @Ron, it's great that you have links for these stretches? Could you summarize some of what the stretches are and post them here as well?

Comment: They're a bit lengthy and I feel a summary won't give them justice. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Ron's link to Yoga Exercises for neck and shoulder pain, the routine in this video for [Yoga at Your Computer to Loosen Tight Upper Back Muscles](http://blog.yoganearme.com/86/yoga-at-your-computer-loosen-upper-back/) I've found very helpful.  Based on the comments, other people have found it useful too.